# iPhone HTTP Request failed by real device

Tags: ios, http

I develop iPhone App which use local rails server for development.
Before the problem, the app could connect to rails server through WiFi.
But, recently the app could not connect to rails server sometimes.

This is the problem I met
1. HTTP Request can not reach to rails server because the rails log do not show nothing.
2. iPhone log show HTTP Request failed because time out.

Environment
1. AFNetworking 3.0.4 I use AFHTTPSessionManager for HTTP Request
2. I user real iPhone devices that are iPhone6s plus iOS 9.2.1, iPhone6 iOS 9.2 and iPhone5s iOS 8.2. All device show same problem.

What I do
1. Changed AFNetworking version 2.6.3 to 3.0.4. But ineffective.
2. Reinstall app. First some times OK. But at a minute same problem occurred.

Anyone know the solution?
I have developed the app for a few months, but recently sudden the problem occurred. I do not know at all why this is happened.

Comment: Did you try using other tools to test your rails server apis, to make sure your server is OK?

Comment: I make a project for testing my HTTP method and the another app can connect to rails server. So, I think my server is OK.

Comment: I tried reboot my mac and I could access my rails server now. But, I am afraid that this is temporary. If the situation change, I will write about it.

Answer (score 0):

for the http request now you need to add those line in your plist    `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
     <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    </dict>`

Answer (score -1):

Starting from iOS9 you should provide NSAppTransportSecurity key value in your plist file to use HTTP (not HTTPS):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

Comment: I know ATS and set the settings. This problem is occurred sometimes. If ATS problem, the problem happens always.